# Relative path for different origin on fetch and import

Tags: javascript, import, fetch

Is relative path resolved differently on fetch and import? I put this script on ipfs (those js doesn't exist; just wanna see complete path on error):

```
fetch("./a.js")
import("./b.js")
```

Included on local html (aws cloud9 in this case):

```
<script src="https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmbNbv2VaAteAHgDbwA2AELvf9YYDAUhQcWg1tZVADztds"></script>
```

Got this error:

```
GET https://[...].vfs.cloud9.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/_static/teste/a.js 400
GET https://ipfs.io/ipfs/b.js net::ERR_ABORTED 400
```

The fetch is looking on aws and import is looking on ipfs. Is it the expected behavior? There is a way to import with relative path with the fetch behavior (lookin on aws directory in this case)? Is it a security risk?

I am using Google Chrome version 89.0.4389.90.

Comment: Could you include the content inside a.js and b.js?

Comment: a.js and b.js doesn't exists. I just wanna show where the browser is looking for them on error message.